# Can I use native plugin in cordova project?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap

I want to use this (https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/blob/master/README.md) in my ionic v1 project for image cropping. 
I know we have plugins in Angular for cropping but I want to use this native plugin for smooth function.

Comment: do you mean Cordova plugin??? Or Angular library??

Comment: I have given the link of the plugin I want to use... It's a native plugin for native Android app

Comment: Is your project developed in Ionic 1 or 2 project??

Comment: Ionic version 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access an external Java file from Ionic1 . You can access a method and get your response.

But if you really want to import the code as a plugin, then you need to create a custom Cordova plugin using plugman plugin. Refer to [this link](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-call-java-method-from-angular-and-get-answer-back-for-android/1167) to access Java method.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but your answer must be self-contained and useful even with the link: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link are regularly deleted](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: @Cody Gray , correctly said but this link is an ionic forum issue, it have list of suggestions and solutions . We can't list everything. And also the solution list in that issue list will be increase day by day . So for this case we should display links I hope for self referral . https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-call-java-method-from-angular-and-get-answer-back-for-android/1167

Comment: That isn't how it works here. Answers are required to be self-contained---the solution must be within the text of the answer itself. It cannot be hidden behind a link.